# Why is PayPal checkout.js much bigger than checkout.src.js?

Tags: paypal

I'm trying to reduce my page load and I'm loading https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js however it is 136k compressed and 877k) uncompressed.  Its contents don't seem minified and there is the comment in the code that says:

> To debug, please use the unminified version of this script at
>   https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.src.js

I looked at https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.src.js and see that it is a mere 56.1k (234k uncompressed).

I performed a basic test with the smaller one locally in sandbox mode and it still shows the incontext window and did a transaction.

I noticed the that the larger https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js does some sort of beacon calls for logging but what justifies the huge increase in size? It's not good for mobile users.  Docs explaining the difference would also be useful.

Is it ok to use https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.src.js ?
It it ok to async the < script> tag too?